# How to output a list to file in R

Tags: r, list

Assume having a list of books with authors , after reading the data into a list "LS" I tried to enter it into a file and the output was

```
> write.table(LS, "output.txt")
Error in data.frame(..., title = NULL,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

> write(LS, "output.txt")
Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) : 
  argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'
```

I was able to use dput but I would like the data to be formatted well (no redundancy of repeated keywords all over the file). Any suggestions?
Thanks

**UPDATE**
dput( head (LS, 2))

```
list(structure(list( title = "Book 1", 
authors = list(structure(c("Pooja", "Garg"),
 .Names = c("forename","surname")), 
structure(c("Renu", "Rastogi"), 
.Names = c("forename","surname")))),
 .Names = c("title", "authors")), 

structure(list( title = "Book 2", 
 authors = list(structure(c("Barry", "Smit"), .Names = c("forename", 
    "surname")), structure(c("Tom", "Johnston"), .Names = c("forename", 
    "surname")))), .Names = c("title", "authors")))
```

Comment: I think you'll need to comment on why you don't think the output of dput is acceptable.  What is your expected/desired output?

Comment: @Dason In dput the keywords "book" and "authors" will be repeated all over the file , while I want them in the header only as csv files.

Comment: placing the some example data will help (how about including `dput(head(LS,2))` within the question so we can see the structure of the data

Comment: Why are you writing to a file?  If it's just for R to read later, use `save` instead.

Comment: @Aaron I want to read the data using Java later , so I don't know if that would work.

Comment: Thanks for the followup, Thomas.  If the data frame method worked for you, please click the check mark by it so others know your problem was solved.  You can also click the up arrow by any question (including the checked one) to signify that the answer was useful, regardless of whether or not it was the solution you ended up using.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may first convert your list to a data frame:

```
LS.df = as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, LS))
```

Or

```
LS.df = as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, LS))
```

Then you can simply save LS.df with write.csv or write.table

Answer (score 9):

Using the data you provided and `rjson`

```
library(rjson)

# write them to a file
cat(toJSON(LS), file = 'LS.json')


LS2 <- fromJSON('LS.json')


# some rearranging to get authors back to being a data.frame

LS3 <- lapply(LS2, function(x) { x[['authors']] <-  lapply(x[['authors']], unlist); x})

identical(LS, LS3)

## TRUE
```

The file looks like

```
[{"title":"Book 1","authors":[{"forename":"Pooja","surname":"Garg"},{"forename":"Renu","surname":"Rastogi"}]},{"title":"Book 2","authors":[{"forename":"Barry","surname":"Smit"},{"forename":"Tom","surname":"Johnston"}]}]
```

## if you want each book on a separate line then you can use

```
.json <-  lapply(LS, toJSON)
# add new lines and braces

.json2 <- paste0('[\n', paste0(.json, collapse = ', \n'), '\n]')
 cat(.json)
[
{"title":"Book 1","authors":[{"forename":"Pooja","surname":"Garg"},{"forename":"Renu","surname":"Rastogi"}]}, 
{"title":"Book 2","authors":[{"forename":"Barry","surname":"Smit"},{"forename":"Tom","surname":"Johnston"}]}
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but the data frame was easier to me

Answer (score 2):

I use the RJSONIO package.

```
library(RJSONIO)

exportJSON <- toJSON(LS)
write(exportJSON,"LS.json")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use format()

`LS.str <- format(LS)`